How to define a generative model using a probability space?
When studying the foundation of probability theory, we learn that we must define a probability space, which is a triple $(\Omega, E, P)$, where $\Omega$ is the set of all outcomes, $E$ is the set of all events, and $P$ is a probability measure that associates a probability to all events in $E$. Then, we learn that a random variable is a measurable function mapping $(\Omega, E, P)$ to a measure space $(X, F)$.
Now, if you study a field like machine learning, you frequently hear about generative models. For example, imagine you toss a fair coin, if it lands head you toss a coin biased toward head, if it lands tail you toss a coin biased towards tail. A generative model of this random process could be as follows:
$$P(X_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.5, 0.5
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad P(X_2 | X_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.9, 0.1 \\
0.1, 0.9
\end{bmatrix}$$
How to express the above generative model using a probability space?
Proposed solution:
The space of possible outcomes is the set of all pairs of head and tail: $\Omega = \{(h, h), (h, t), (t, h), (t, t)\}$
The event space is the power set of the outcome space: $E = 2^\Omega$
The probability measure is given by: $\forall e \in E, P(e) = \sum_{\omega \in e} P(\omega)$
Let $X = \{h, t\}$, and $F = 2^X$. We now define the following random variables:
$$X_i:\Omega \rightarrow X \quad s.t. \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega,\, \forall i \in \{1, 2\},\, X_i(\omega) = X_i(\omega_1, \omega_2) = \omega_i,$$
thus, the $i$-th random variable extracts $\omega_i$, i.e., the $i$-th element in the pair $\omega$.
The only thing left is to define $P(\omega)$, can we define it as follows:
$$P(\omega) = P(\omega_1, \omega_2) = P(X_1 = \omega_1, X_2 = \omega_2) = P(X_1 = \omega_1)P(X_2 = \omega_2 | X_1 = \omega_1),$$
where:
$$P(X_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.5, 0.5
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad P(X_2 | X_1) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.9, 0.1 \\
0.1, 0.9
\end{bmatrix}$$
Is my proposed solution correct?

Looks right to me.
